# SQL Row deleting by itself

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

I have an MySQL database table where users input a form and a row gets added to my table.

After filling out the form, my row gets added to the table instantly.

All seems fine, but about 10 seconds later, it vanishes. I keep refreshing the table and it stays there about ten seconds and after about the fifth refresh, it disappears.

I have tried many different combos of inputs and it still does the same thing.

Anyone have a suggestion?? What would cause this strange behavior?

Query:

```
INSERT INTO TableName ("Column1", "Column2")
VALUES ('$name', '$phone')
```

Keep in mind it does get added. The row is physically in my table (using phpMyAdmin).

When I refresh, ten seconds later it's gone. All of my old rows are there.

Complete code in PHP:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table ( NamePerson, Game, Price, Method, BestOffer, Email, Phone, UniqueID, Location, Bowl) 
         VALUES ( '$name', '$game', '$price', '$method', '$best', '$email', '$phone', '$uniqueID', '$location', '$bowl' )";
$results = mysql_query($sql);
if($results) { echo "success";}
```

Comment: what is your query ? put your code in question

Comment: @MahmoodRehman I added an edit of code. Not sure how that helps since the query does work, and the row is in the table for about ten seconds.

Comment: It's magic, we cannot help you :^ )

Comment: First time in my life i see that insert query deleting records.Sorry dear this is not the actual code.if you need help than provide all the query code.this is insertion code not deletion.

Comment: @sectus haha i am baffled. I have no triggers, cron jobs, or anything that would cause this. I refresh immediately after posting and it is there. Refresh again, gone. :(

Comment: @mahmoodrehman You misunderstand my question. My insert above INSERTS the row. I check my table, and yes the row is there. All is well. Refresh my phpMyAdmin page again, it's gone. No query executed.

Comment: are you using innodb and transactions? failing to commit would do that

Comment: @kaiQing I do not know what innodb and transactions are, so no:(

Comment: can you post the complete php chunk that inserts the entry?

Comment: Turn on general log query. And explore it.

Comment: @KaiQing I have edited with my full code. No other queries are ran after this.

Comment: Ok looks normal. Can you click on the table in phpmyadmin, then click operations at the top and verify the table is set to MyISAM, which does not support transactions. So if for some goofy reason this is a weird transactional autocommit setting just changing to MyISAM should disable whatever may be happening there. I've never heard of this happening and it sounds preposterous to me, but worth looking into just to be sure. Also, as sectus said, checking the logs would be the sane place to begin hunting

Comment: @KaiQing Just checked the Storage Engine and it is indeed MyISAM. It is running on a shared server provided by my host. Am I able to view the logs?

Comment: They would be the ones to answer that. You'd need to ask them how to access logs if they don't provide an interface for it. Also, does this kind of insert error happen on any other tables?

Comment: @KaiQing It seems to be only this table. If I click on EDIT on the row right before it deletes, change nothing and then click SAVE, it seems to stay... Something wrong in my table structure? Not sure why the SQL would add it, then immediately delete it if that were the case??

Comment: Run an `INSERT` through `MySQL` console and see it the behavior is still the same. Run `DESCRIBE TableName;` and post the output here for inspection.

Answer (score 0):

1) You might be using some "INTERVAL" concept of MySQL
2) Are you doing some rollback/delete, down the line in your code for some exception.

The SQL which you have given is plain and simple.

Comment: No rollback or delete. Checked for any interval columns, and don't have any.

Comment: Your DB must have a trigger, which is deleting the table entry after insertion. Can you recall, if you have created any trigger for deletion ?

Comment: Use the command SHOW TRIGGERS, this will display the trigger if you have any in your database.

Comment: Ran it, yielded nothing. I have contacted my host's support maybe it is something not on my end.

Comment: Is it possible something malicious is on the server end? After further investigation, manually adding queries does the same thing. So not on my PHP end! Also, it now ranges from 10 seconds to 5 minutes until it auto deletes.... hmm.

Comment: Yeah..there are settings on mysql config files on server, where we can set the auto increment setting. Like wise, periodic deletion is also possible. Great that you contacted your host's support. Hopefully the issue will resolve as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Is autocommit OFF?

Execute the following statement:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'autocommit';
```

If the value if OFF, then that would explain the transaction being rolled-back.